# Opencv isn't able to open camera

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I wrote an OpenCV application, everything runs fine except that OpenCV isn't able to open the camera. I already tested the camera works fine with cheese and also with the next commands utilities:

```
fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 85 -DE 1 webcam-shot.jpg
```

and also

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -vframes 1 test1.jpg
```

Everything works fine; the next example to run a video file run fine:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('reporte actual.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but when tried to use the camera the function `isOpened()` always returns false:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(cap.get(3))
print(cap.isOpened())
cap.release()
```

I'm use:

- kubuntu 18.04 64 bits
- python 3.6.5
- OpenCV 4.0.0-pre

I tested this same code in a PC with ubuntu 16.04 64 bits and is running fine, the line

```
print(cap.get(3))
```

get me the resolution of the camera and the function `isOpened()` returns true; I have already enable the ffmpeg support in OpenCV:

```
 Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (ver 2.2.5)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.107.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 57.83.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 55.78.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 4.8.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 3.7.0)
    GStreamer:                   
      base:                      YES (ver 1.14.1)
      video:                     YES (ver 1.14.1)
      app:                       YES (ver 1.14.1)
      riff:                      YES (ver 1.14.1)
      pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.14.1)
    gPhoto2:                     NO
```

The gstreamer libraries are installed in my PC, when I run the then commands I'm able to see the colors bar video display

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! xvimagesink
```

the next command

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

shows this output:

```
USB 2.0 Camera: HD 720P Webcam (usb-0000:00:14.0-14):
        /dev/video0
```

so until here everything is ok; when I run the application from the command line I get the next answer:

```
gstreamer-critical ** gst_element_get_state assertion 'gst_is_element (element)' failed
```

In order to take a picture for analysis, I replace the OpenCV camera handle with:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -vframes 1 test1.jpg
```

and then I'm able to make the analysis I need to do; so the only problem is in the OpenCV camera handle... any idea?

Comment: I would recommend not to use OpenCV 4.0, since it is not considered as release yet :) it may have more bugs. Other than that, you can try to use the FFMPEG as backend. `cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)`

Answer (score 0):

You have the beginning with accessing the camera with

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

To read frames from the camera, use

```
ret, frame=cap.read()
```

To display the frames in a window, use

```
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

And to display a stream, use

```
while True:
    ret, frame=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

Comment: hello Mike thanks for your answer; the problem is that OpenCV isn't able to use the camera, before start to read frames from the camera I'm using the function cap.IsOpened(), is this function return a false then is not posible to read frames from the camera.